# knockoutjs - javascript array to observableArray to template - how to?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a page that contains information for a subscriber, their spouse, and N number of dependents.

For each one, we're asking for their name, dob, address, etc.  Basically, it's the same fields over and over.  I can create a model for the subscriber and the spouse. I'll always have a subscriber, and I'm not worried about creating an empty spouse node in my model, but for the kids, I'm unsure how to proceed...

My page is a very long page with lots of sections that will be hidden until it's time to deal with that section- like a wizard.

Each section in my current page starts with an outer div:

```
<div data-bind="with: submodelName">  // i.e. subscriberInfo, spouseInfo
```

I just don't know how to proceed with the N number of children.

I can stuff an entire <div><form></form><div> section into a <script> tag and make it a template, but how do I bind a different model to each item?  i.e. how do I simulate the "with:" part?

My current model set up is that I have a large wrapping model into which I'm creating many submodels (4 + one for each child) and calling a single applyBindings():

```
var masterPageModel = new PageViewModel(); // pulls in several other modules

    // ... pageViewModel.js contents::

    // *** section-specific models
    self.selectedCoverage = ko.observable();
    self.contactInformation = ko.observable();
    self.subscriberInformation = ko.observable();
    self.spouseInformation = ko.observable();
    self.dependentInformation = ko.observableArray(); // how will this work? array?

    $.getJSON("./load.php",{},function(modelPackage){

         // **** meta properties
         self.modelList(modelPackage.modelList);
         self.currentModel(modelPackage.currentModel);

         // models
         self.selectedCoverage(new SelectedCoverage(modelPackage.models["selectedCoverage"]));
         self.contactInformation(new ContactInformation(modelPackage.models["contactInformation"]));
         self.subscriberInformation(new SubscriberInformation(modelPackage.models["subscriberInformation"]));
         self.dependentInformation(new DependentInformation(modelPackage.models["dependentInformation"]));  // this isn't working
         // dependentInformation is an array of people and information....

    }); 

    //... back to first file:

ko.applyBindings(masterPageModel);
```

Thanks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott, not sure I understand completely, but this may help:

### Only One Form

One approach would be to display an "add dependent" button, a list of dependent names for the user to select, and then only show a single form to edit (or add) the selected dependent.  Excuse my pseudocode, but something like this:

```
myModel = {
    myDependents = ko.observableArray(dependents);
    mySelectedDependentIndex = ko.observable(0);
    myActiveDependent = ko.computed(function(){ return myDependents()[mySelectedDependentIndex()];});
}
```

Then bind your form to the model's `myActiveDependent` computed observable.

### One Form for Each Dependent

Another approach would be to use the `foreach` binding.

```
myModel = {
    myDependents = ko.observableArray(dependents);        
}

myDependentModel = {
    name = ko.observable('someName');
}

<div id="dependentFormListContainer">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: myDependents">
        <li class="dependentForm">
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

ko.applyBindings(myModel, $('#dependentFormListContainer')[0]);
```

Again, this is all pseudocode, but hopefully that will point you in the direction of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can use the if binding like this:

```
<!-- ko 'if': valueIsWhatIAmLookingFor -->
<div data-bind='template: myTemplate'>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I escape the 'if' for IE.